# set a value in a html-array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an array of input-fields and via an ajax-call I receive values which I want to put in the array:

```
<input id="startdateinput[0]" type="text" value="2014-01-01">
<input id="startdateinput[1]" type="text" value="">
<input id="startdateinput[2]" type="text" value="">
```

The XML looks something like:

```
    <item key='0'>
      <startdate>2014-01-01</startdate>
    </item>
    <item key='1'>
      <startdate>2014-02-01</startdate>
    </item
```

I use jQuery something like:

```
    $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
        startdate=$(this).find('startdate').text();
        key=$(this).attr('key');
        $("#startdate["+key+"]").attr("value",startdate);
    });
```

Nothing happens....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use

```
$("#startdateinput\\["+key+"\\]").val(startdate);
```

Your id is starting with `startdateinput` so need to escape the `[` and `]`, also use .val() to set the value

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ncL2eL7t/)

Comment: That's real quick and most of all: it works! Thanks!